# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Multi-tenant with separate database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am following [this sample](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5518/multi-tenant-asp-net-core-5---implementing-database-per-tenant-strategy) by Gunnar Peipman to create a multi-tenant architecture in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. It is working as expected up to the point shown in the sample.

```
public class Tenant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public interface ITenantProvider
{
    Tenant GetTenant();
}

public class DummyTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private static IList<Tenant> _tenants = new List<Tenant>
    {
        new Tenant { Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant1Id, Name = "Imaginary corp", DatabaseConnectionString = "ConnStr1" },
        new Tenant { Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant2Id, Name = "The Very Big corp", DatabaseConnectionString = "ConnStr2" },
    };

    public Tenant GetTenant()
    {
        return _tenants.First();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Registering the services in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MultitenantDbContext>(o => { });

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<ITenantProvider, DummyTenantProvider>();
}
```

MultitenantDbContext.cs

```
public class MultitenantDbContext : DbContext
{
    public static Guid Tenant1Id = Guid.Parse("51aab199-1482-4f0d-8ff1-5ca0e7bc525a");
    public static Guid Tenant2Id = Guid.Parse("ae4e21fa-57cb-4733-b971-fdd14c4c667e");

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    private Tenant _tenant;
    private ILogger<MultitenantDbContext> _logger;

    public MultitenantDbContext(ITenantProvider tenantProvider, ILogger<MultitenantDbContext> logger)
    {
        _tenant = tenantProvider.GetTenant();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // Comment out for real application
        //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_tenant.DatabaseConnectionString);

        // Comment in for real applications
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.TenantId == _tenant.Id);
    }

    public void AddSampleData()
    {
        People.Add(new Person
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("79865406-e01b-422f-bd09-92e116a0664a"),
            TenantId = Tenant1Id,
            FirstName = "Gunnar",
            LastName = "Peipman"
        });

        People.Add(new Person
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("d5674750-7f6b-43b9-b91b-d27b7ac13572"),
            TenantId = Tenant2Id,
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Doe"
        });

        People.Add(new Person
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("e41446f9-c779-4ff6-b3e5-752a3dad97bb"),
            TenantId = Tenant1Id,
            FirstName = "Mary",
            LastName = "Jones"
        });

        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I now want to dynamically select a tenant depending upon the domain host of the application. For this, I modified the `DummyTenantProvider` and injected `IHttpContextAccessor` to access the request's `HttpContext` and extract the domain host. Is the approach given below correct?

```
public class DummyTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public DummyTenantProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private readonly static IList<Tenant> _tenants = new List<Tenant>
    {
        new Tenant { Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant1Id, Name = "Imaginary corp", DatabaseConnectionString = "ConnStr1", Host = "mywebhost.com" },
        new Tenant { Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant2Id, Name = "The Very Big corp", DatabaseConnectionString = "ConnStr2", Host = "anotherhost.com" },
    };

    public Tenant GetTenant()
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        return _tenants.Single(t => t.Host == httpContext.Request.Host.Host);
    }
}
```